# LINQ query performance when applying Where clause

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have a question about Entity Framework.

I would be grateful if someone can kindly explain some details of how the chain calls work between LINQ and Entity Framework (and at what point the query is executed on the DB side).

I’d like to know the performance differences (if any) of writing out a LINQ query in two versions of the methods below:

Method 1:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetList(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, params     Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    var results = dbSet.Where(expression).AsQueryable().AsNoTracking();
    return includeProperties.Aggregate(results, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
}
```

Function call like this:

```
GetList(x => x.ID == id);
```

Method 2:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetList(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    var results = dbSet.AsQueryable().AsNoTracking();
    return includeProperties.Aggregate(results, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
}
```

Function call like this:

```
GetList().Where(x => x.ID == id);
```

Comment: What is `includeProperties` ?

Comment: Deferred execution in both cases, queries will not be fired before you actually access the data. E.g. by calling ToList or loop through it.

Comment: includeProperties is the top level optional LINQ query in the form of an expression acceptable by the methods

Comment: thanks Ako, are you saying that the example function call for method 1 is in effect the same as the exmaple call for Method 2 in terms of data been retrieved from DB

Comment: @Ako is correct that the execution will be deferred in both cases, however, what is deferred is vastly different.  See my answer below as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that your routines are returning an `IEnumerable<T>` instead of an `IQueryable<T>`.  In your second case, the Where will use the IEnumerable's version instead of IQueryable's.  The "chaining" sort of stops there (The server-side chain stops, and a client-side chain begins).  No more changes after that point will have any effect on the SQL that is generated.  Once you try and enumerate the results, it will cause all the records to be returned from the datasource and then be filtered on the client side where the first will filter on the datasource side because you did the Where while it was still an IQueryable.

Change your routines to return an `IQueryable<T>` instead, and then they should be identical in terms of execution and performance.

** Side note, in Method 1, the .AsQueryable() is redundant.  It's already an IQueryable.

This is how I would expect such a function to be written:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetList(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
  var results = dbSet.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();
  return includeProperties.Aggregate(results, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply Robert, can you elaborate more please do you mean to say that if the method returns `IQueryable<T>` the data will not be returned straight away and the query is still been built. If so at what point is the data returned down the line hence the topic of my question.

Comment: Actually I get the point from your latest edited answer that to me explains it. So returning a `IQueryable<T>` will in fact deffer the chaining from completing on the DB side until some data manipulation is done (as initially pointed out be @Ako) or some sort of collection is returned instead like a `IEnumerable`

Comment: This particular function could also be rewritten as an extension on DbSet as well, and then you could use it on any DbSet.